# Показывать сразу или облегчить просмотр ответов в очереди на закрытие

Tags: предложение, очередь-проверок

Сейчас при проверке вопросов в очереди «[вопросы на закрытие](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/close)» на странице отображается собственно текст вопроса и комментарии к нему.

Во многих, не совсем очевидных, ситуациях просмотр **ответов** (при их наличии) помогает принять более взвешенное решение.

А для просмотра ответов приходится (а) открывать отдельную страницу с самим вопросом, (б) переключаться на неё (ну, это у кого как настроено), а затем (в) закрывать.

Было бы значительно удобнее обойтись без этих лишних действий.

---

Отсюда предложение: либо сразу показывать ответы на странице проверки, либо хотя бы добавить кнопку, с помощью которой их можно подгрузить прямо на эту же страницу.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не раз просили на MSE:

- [See other answers in Low Quality Review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/144259/260198).
- [Show answers on review page for questions flagged as "unclear what you're asking"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/227139/260198).
- [Showing Whole Threads in Answer-Review Section](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148739/260198).
- [Show answers when reviewing questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/152990/260198).
- [Please put answers underneath questions in Close review queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/172931/260198).

Но, судя по всему, команда SE этого делать не планирует.

Можно попробовать поставить неофициальный юзерскрипт [Stack Overflow Unofficial Patch v1.10](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/the-stack-overflow-unofficial-patch-soup).

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]